# Replace na in column by value corresponding to column name in seperate table

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),A = c(1,4,NA,NA,4),B = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),C= c(1,2,3,4,NA))

> data
  ID  A  B  C
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  4  2  2
3  3 NA NA  3
4  4 NA NA  4
5  5  4 NA NA
```

I have a mapping file as well which looks like this

```
reference <- data.frame(Names = c("A","B","C"),Vals = c(2,5,6))

> reference
  Names Vals
1     A    2
2     B    5
3     C    6
```

I want my data file to be modified using the reference file in a way which would yield me this final data frame

```
> final_data
  ID A B C
1  1 1 1 1
2  2 4 2 2
3  3 2 5 3
4  4 2 5 4
5  5 4 5 6
```

What is the fastest way I can acheive this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `Map`

```
data[as.character(reference$Names)] <- Map(function(x,y) replace(x, 
         is.na(x), y), data[as.character(reference$Names)], reference$Vals)
data
#  ID A B C
#1  1 1 1 1
#2  2 4 2 2
#3  3 2 5 3
#4  4 2 5 4
#5  5 4 5 6
```

EDIT: Based on @thelatemail's comments.

NOTE: NO external packages used

---

As we are looking for efficient solution, another approach would be `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
v1 <- as.character(reference$Names)

for(j in seq_along(v1)){
  set(data, i = which(is.na(data[[v1[j]]])), j= v1[j], value = reference$Vals[j]  )
 }
```

NOTE: Only a single efficient external package used.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some way of making sure the ordering matches between the two sets of values, like `Map(function(d,r) replace(d, is.na(d), r), data[as.character(reference$Names)], reference$Vals )` ? Otherwise you're relying on everything being in the same order of rows vs columns.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to compute a logical matrix of the target columns capturing which cells are NA. We can then index-assign the NA cells with the replacement values. The tricky part is ensuring the replacement vector aligns with the indexed cells:

```
im <- is.na(data[as.character(reference$Names)]);
data[as.character(reference$Names)][im] <- rep(reference$Vals,colSums(im));
data;
##   ID A B C
## 1  1 1 1 1
## 2  2 4 2 2
## 3  3 2 5 3
## 4  4 2 5 4
## 5  5 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If `reference` was the same wide format as `data`, dplyr's new (v. 0.5.0) `coalesce` function is built for replacing `NA`s; together with `purrr`, which offers alternate notations for `*apply` functions, it makes the process very simple:

```
library(dplyr)

# spread reference to wide, add ID column for mapping
reference_wide <- data.frame(ID = NA_real_, tidyr::spread(reference, Names, Vals))

reference_wide

#   ID A B C
# 1 NA 2 5 6

# now coalesce the two column-wise and return a df
purrr::map2_df(data, reference_wide, coalesce)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# 
#      ID     A     B     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     4     2     2
# 3     3     2     5     3
# 4     4     2     5     4
# 5     5     4     5     6
```